# Plot single data with two Y axes (two units) in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot a single time series, but want to represent it in two units on left and right axes. Here's what I have done so far.

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
t = np.arange(1,50,1)
s1 = np.sin(t)*20000+40000 #synthetic ts, but closer to my data 
ax1.plot(t, s1, 'b-')

ax1.set_xlabel('time')
ax1.set_ylim(20000,70000)
ax1.set_ylabel('km3/year')

km3yearToSv=31.6887646*(1/1e6)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
s2 = s1*km3yearToSv
ax2.plot(t, s2, 'b-')
ax2.set_ylim(20000*km3yearToSv,70000*km3yearToSv)
ax2.set_ylabel('Sv')
```

[image]

By adjusting the ylim(), I can get it to seem as a single line, but some aliasing can be seen. I would prefer if I don't have to plot the data twice.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE: Thanks, askewchan, for the perfect solution!

Comment: Can you include your whole script?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no need to plot it twice, this much should give you the result you want:

```
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.set_ylim(20000*km3yearToSv, 70000*km3yearToSv)
ax2.set_ylabel('Sv')
```

A more robust way to do it is to first extract the limits of the plot (in case you change them, and they're no longer `20000` and `70000`, or you want the plot to be able to automatically adjust the limits:

```
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
mn, mx = ax1.get_ylim()
ax2.set_ylim(mn*km3yearToSv, mx*km3yearToSv)
ax2.set_ylabel('Sv')
```

[image: one plot]

Altogether, with some other small tweaks:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mean, amp = 40000, 20000
t = np.arange(50)
s1 = np.sin(t)*amp + mean #synthetic ts, but closer to my data 

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot(t, s1, 'b-')

ax1.set_xlabel('time')
mn, mx = ax1.set_ylim(mean-amp, mean+amp)
ax1.set_ylabel('km$^3$/year')

km3yearToSv = 31.6887646e-6

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.set_ylim(mn*km3yearToSv, mx*km3yearToSv)
ax2.set_ylabel('Sv')
```

Comment: Just a note, this will only work for units that share a linear relationship

Answer (score 1):

one small error in code above:

```
mn, mx = ax2.get_ylim()
```

should be:

```
mn, mx = ax1.get_ylim()
```

to scale new secondary axis based on original.