# How to plot a curve with two y-axes that are not mathematicly related to each other

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a text file where each line contains pressure, height, and temperature. I want to draw the temperature curve in terms of height and pressure (two y-axes). But I have trouble synchronizing the y-axes together. This question may sound like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66301881/plotly-plotting-one-trace-with-two-x-axes-that-are-not-linearly-related) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32662642/plot-single-data-with-two-y-axes-two-units-in-matplotlib), but note that unlike them, the y-axes here are not mathematically related to each other.

First I tried to use `twinx()` to plot the temperature in terms of height (blue) and pressure (red) separately and make one of the curves disappear.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from metpy.cbook import get_test_data


# Obtaining Upper air data from of MetPy's sample data.
col_names = ['pressure', 'height', 'temperature']

df = pd.read_fwf(get_test_data('jan20_sounding.txt', as_file_obj=False),
                 skiprows=5, usecols=[0, 1, 2], names=col_names)

# Drop any rows with all NaN values for T (Temperature)
df = df.dropna(subset=['temperature'], how='all').reset_index(drop=True)

h = df['height'].values
p = df['pressure'].values
T = df['temperature'].values

# Ploting data
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(T, h, color='blue')
ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='blue')
ax2=ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(T, p, color='red')
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', colors='red')
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()

plt.show()
```

But, as can be seen in the following image, the curves do not match because of the lack of a linear relationship between the y-axes. So, the y-axis tick labels are not synchronized to each other. For example, the '800' label should be placed at the level of the blue curve's peak.

[image]

In the next attempt, I used `set_yticks` for the second y-axis (pressure).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from metpy.cbook import get_test_data


# Obtaining Upper air data from of MetPy's sample data.
col_names = ['pressure', 'height', 'temperature']

df = pd.read_fwf(get_test_data('jan20_sounding.txt', as_file_obj=False),
                 skiprows=5, usecols=[0, 1, 2], names=col_names)

# Drop any rows with all NaN values for T (Temperature)
df = df.dropna(subset=['temperature'], how='all').reset_index(drop=True)

h = df['height'].values
p = df['pressure'].values
T = df['temperature'].values

# pp=[p[i] for i in range(0, len(p), 10)]

# Ploting data
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(T, h, color='blue')
ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='blue')
ax2=ax.twinx()
ax2.set_yticks([p[i] for i in range(0, len(p), 10)])
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', colors='red')
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()

plt.show()
```

But the result is not desirable, because the pressure labels are not aligned with the temperature curve. For example, the '978' label should be in front of the starting point of the curve.

[image]

The problem may become easier if we just want to display the pressure labels in a few predefined levels, for example [900, 800, 500, 300, 100], in their right places compared to the height axis. The final output can look like the following image:

[image]

Comment: I might be wrong because I lack the context, but I don't think it's a good idea to use secondary axis to visualize not-mathematically-related and unevenly-spaced ticks. Instead, ``annotate`` or ``axhline`` could work well for this purpose. This is my personal opinion, feel free to ignore.

Comment: If I add `ax2.plot(T, p, color='red')` to the second code, won't it draw the expected output? I will expand it to [Google  Collab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1yA7m2NAeV6ATjpXg8WeSdNk3BpDzlte8?usp=sharing), please check. If you are missing the point, delete this comment.